# Cross platform C++ UDP socket library

Tags: c++, networking

Can somebody recommend a free C++ open source library which I will use to build a networked game using UDP. Must be available for Windows/Linux/Mac. As lightweight as possible please.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want the library to solve? When "lightweight" is your only requirement, the correct answer would be "no library - use plain sockets". But obviously there is some other requirement you want to have fulfilled. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some libraries which may do even more than what you need, not very light weight but completely reliable I think you can even use the *Net* portion of the library instead using them as a whole:

- [SDL net](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net)
- [Boost:ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html)

you can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library).

Comment: Have SDL downloaded now. Will try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://enet.bespin.org/.

Comment: Will do. Have heard about enet so its worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/); it's relatively lightweight and implements a virtual connection over UDP for you (you don't have to manually send acks). I've had great success in using it across multiple projects.